# NameError: name 'TigerXtrm' is not defined

Tags: python, mongodb, ubuntu, hostable-web-core

I'm in the process of installing a piece of software from Github: https://github.com/bravecollective/core

It uses MongoDB, Python and WebCore to run. I've managed to get it running and now I've arrived at the part where I need to make myself an admin user. According to the readme, the following needs to be executed in the Paster shell.

```
from brave.core.account.model import User
from brave.core.character.model import EVECharacter
from brave.core.permission.model import Permission, WildcardPermission
u = User.objects(username=USERNAME_HERE)[0]
u.admin = True
c = u.primary
p1 = Permission.objects(id='core.*').first()
c.personal_permissions.append(p1)
c.save()
u.save()
```

The username in this case being 'TigerXtrm'. However, when I do this it comes back with the following:

```
Welcome to the WebCore shell.
from brave.core.account.model import User
from brave.core.character.model import EVECharacter
 from brave.core.permission.model import Permission, WildcardPermission
 u = User.objects(username=TigerXtrm)[0]
c = u.primary
p1 = Permission.objects(id='core.*').first()
c.personal_permissions.append(p1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "console", line 1, in module
NameError: name 'TigerXtrm' is not defined
```

So **NameError: name 'TigerXtrm' is not defined** is what creates a problem for me. The user is created and has been entered into the MongoDB database, I've also tried lowercase and e-mail adress, both to no avail. I can't figure out why it's telling me it's not defined. Am I executing it in the wrong place or is there something wrong with the code? Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 1):

That's the Python interpreter complaining because you need to quote TigerXtrm:

```
u = User.objects(username="TigerXtrm")[0]
```